# Handling AJAX with custom taxonomy custom fields on add

Tags: custom-taxonomy, ajax, javascript

I wrote some extra fields for my custom taxonomy. I added the form fields to the add form. I got it to save by handling the appropriate values in `$_POST`. In 4.1.x, the add form is Ajax-ified. How can I clear out the form fields on success?

More specifically, how can I view the response to the `add-tag` admin ajax action?

Comment: Please post your javascript AJAX request code, there is an argument of the AJAX code reserved for a callback on success or failure and this would be the best place to reset the fields.

Comment: i'm not making any outside of the core functionality.
i'm pigging back on the existing WP functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with a little bit of jQuery:

Create this file within THEMEFOLDER/js/ called field-clear.js and replace `#formID` with the ID of the form you would like to reset:

```
//Code runs when an ajax request succeeds
jQuery( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    //Check ajax action of request that succeeded
    if(settings.action == 'add_tag') {
        //Reset the form
        jQuery('#formID')[0].reset();

        //Send ajax response to console.
        console.log("Triggered ajaxSuccess handler. The ajax response was: " + xhr.responseText );
    }
});
```

Then in functions.php load your javascript:

```
wp_register_script('field-clear-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/field-clear.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

function field_clear_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('field-clear-script');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'field_clear_load_scripts');
```

EDIT - Added code to display ajax response text.  Added check for ajax action parameter.  Changed enqueue function to enqueue on admin as I think this is where it's required.

Comment: a little regex on settings.data and all is well, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Jason's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179760/27856) is very close, which led to this solution for me on WP 4.9:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(evt, xhr, opts) {
    if (
        xhr.status >= 200
        && xhr.status < 300
        && opts.data
        && /(^|&)action=add-tag($|&)/.test(opts.data)
        && /(^|&)taxonomy=YOUR_TAXONOMY($|&)/.test(opts.data)
        && xhr.responseXML
        && $('wp_error', xhr.responseXML).length == 0
    ) {
        // clear your fields
    }
});
```